# При получение фрагмента возвращает null

Tags: android, android-fragment, textview, null, android-viewpager

Есть адаптер

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
        this.titles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position)
    {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

В Классе активити устанавливаю к ViewPager два фрагмента

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ListWordFragment(), "Список");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AddWordFragment(), "Добавить слово");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

И в Классе того же активити получаю второй фрагмент и в TextView устанавливаю текст

```
Fragment fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
        ((TextView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.info2_textView)).setText("Loll");
```

И при выполнение кода мне выдает ошибку что текст возвращает null

```
06-27 16:20:02.916 22266-22266/ru.landmarkstd.educt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: ru.landmarkstd.educt, PID: 22266
                                                                      Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.landmarkstd.educt/ru.landmarkstd.educt.Word}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at ru.landmarkstd.educt.Word.onCreate(Word.java:60)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Первый фрагмент 
Класс

```
public class ListWordFragment extends Fragment
{
    public View v;
    public ListView listView;
    ListViewClearAdapter listAdapter;
    ArrayList<itemSelect> itemSelects = new ArrayList<itemSelect>();

    public ListWordFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_word, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        itemSelects.add(new itemSelect("test1", "Org","", false));
        itemSelects.add(new itemSelect("test2", "Org","", false));
        itemSelects.add(new itemSelect("test3", "Org","", false));

        listAdapter = new ListViewClearAdapter(v.getContext(), itemSelects);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        return v;
    }

}
```

XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.ListWordFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Второй фрагмент 
класс

```
 public class AddWordFragment extends Fragment
{
    public AddWordFragment()
    {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_word, container, false);
    }

}
```

XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.AddWordFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Word_editText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Слово"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/MyEditText"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*Внесите в скобки (Квадратные или круглые) букву которую надо заменить, пример: С(о)рока"
            android:id="@+id/Info1_textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Варианты ответов"
            android:id="@+id/text1_textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Answer_editText"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:hint="Ответ"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditText"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="146dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Добавить ответ"
                android:id="@+id/addAnswer_button"
                android:background="#6acbda"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*Отметьте правильный ответ"
            android:id="@+id/info2_textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="378dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Добавить слово"
            android:id="@+id/addWord_button"
            android:background="#5dc8d8"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Класс Word

```
public class Word extends AppCompatActivity
{

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    String type;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        new NavigationDrawer(this, toolbar, 0);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");

        switch (type)
        {
            case "add":
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Добавление списка");
                break;
            case "edit":
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Редактирование списка");
                break;
        }

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ListWordFragment(), "Список");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AddWordFragment(), "Добавить слово");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        Fragment fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
        Log.d("myLog", String.valueOf(fragment.getView()));
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, скинь код fragment как одного так и другого, с их xml layout

Comment: @ЕвгенийСуетин Обновил

Comment: Что за класс ```Word``` ?

Comment: @temq Это основное активити точнее класс основного активити

Comment: Покажите его код

Comment: @temq обновил в самом низу

Comment: какая 60 строка в классе ```Word```? Важно чтобы эта строка была именно той строкой, которая была ей при краше.

Comment: @temq         'Fragment fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
        Log.d("myLog", String.valueOf(fragment.getView()));'